# Can't download ePub with Aldiko

Tags: aldiko, epub

Recently I received via email an `.epub` file (eBook). When I try to download it I get an error message that says "Aucune application ne peux afficher la pièce jointe" (no application can show the attached file).

There was a short time I don't read on my Android phone, so when I have the first error message I have uninstalled and reinstalled the [Aldiko](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.aldiko.android) app.

But my phone still tells me with "Aucune application ne peux afficher la pièce jointe" (no application can show the attached file).

Has anyone had the same problem? Does anyone have a resolution?

Comment: Have you tried download the .epub to your computer and transferring it to your phone? Also, What phone? what version of Android?

Comment: Android 4.0.4 on Samsung Galaxy SII (I9100 i think). Erh... i don't have any cable with me & my computer don't have bluetooth nor wifi.

Comment: Do you have dropbox or google drive?

Comment: seems to be blocked in my computer (but i have it in my phone, i could try in a other place...). Except if it always possible to send a document to GDrive via email...

Comment: What app you are using to download/retrieve the `.epub` file?

Comment: Gmail (native). I admit i don't try with the browser :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple solutions. As I don't know how you tried to download it (or with which app you received it), I'll give you a few "blind shots":

- **Downloading it with the browser:** This might give you the error you described (see below for a possible solution on this), or might simply store the file in your downloads folder (depending on the browser used). In the latter case, the saved file is often mis-named to `.epub.html`, so you'd have to rename it and strip the `.html` off to be able to open the book with your reader.
- **Receiving it with the mail/gmail app:** There should be a way to simply "save the attachment" to your sdcard. You need to find the correct folder with some eBook readers; Aldiko might offer you to import it to its library from wherever you've stored it.
- **Downloading it with your PC, and copying it to your device:** Same steps as above after saving the attachment.
- **Try [Moon+ Reader](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.flyersoft.moonreader) as alternative eBook Reader app:** As far as I remember, *Moon+* registers itself for the `.epub` extension, which should completely solve your problem with the error message (the book would be opened directly in *Moon+ Reader*). And even if not, it has a lot of OPDS libraries pre-configured where you can download books from directly from within the app.

One or more of above items should help you out of your misery. Enjoy eBook reading!

PS: If you like *Moon+*: Until the end of this month (February 28, 2013), the Pro version ([Moon+ Reader Pro](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.flyersoft.moonreaderp)) is offered for half of its usual price to celebrate its return to the playstore after having been unfairly banned. This is an offer you *should* take then :)

Comment: Glad I could help! Enjoy reading :)